# Uninstalling Heroku CLI broke apt in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, heroku, apt

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and I've followed the instructions, [Uninstalling the Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#uninstalling-the-heroku-cli).

```
sudo apt-get remove heroku
sudo apt-key del <Heroku's key from 'apt-key list'>
```

I didn't uninstall `heroku-toolbelt` package since it was not found.
Also `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/heroku.list` doesn't exist.

Problem arises when I do subsequent `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt dist-upgrade`.

```
Err:7 https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt ./ InRelease
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C927EBE00F1B0520
...
...
...
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt ./ InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C927EBE00F1B0520
W: Failed to fetch https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt/./InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C927EBE00F1B0520
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I guess `apt-key del` broke the apt but I wanted to completely uninstall Heroku-CLI (which included the key) as I no longer need it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Running

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r "deb https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt ./"
```

Solved the problem.